# Таблица в диве

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, есть div

```
<div id="m65f" style="width: 640px; border:1px solid #CCC; height:199px; margin-top:70px; margin-left:300px; float:right; background:#F5F5F5;position:absolute; ">

</div>
```

В нем находится таблица

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="20">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Но таблица выводится почему-то не внутри дива, хотя она вписана в див, а поверх его как отдельный элемент и все части таблицы на экране, а надо чтобы были только те, которые влезли в див, а то, что из ячеек таблицы не влезло в длину дива, были как бы в нем спрятаны, подскажите, как это можно сделать? Вроде в верстке все нормально, а показываются таблицы вверху дива, а не внутри и полностью. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы использовали что-либо на подобии `reset.css`? 
Если нет, попробуйте в таблицы обнулить `margin`.

Грубо говоря, добавьте в `CSS`:

```
#m65f,#m65f table{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PZ2fx/
Что не так?
Табличка внутри дива.

Если таблица выползает за границы дива, то пробуйте поставить диву:
overflow: hidden;
Все, что будет вылазить из под дива будет грубо обрезаться.